How to Clear Value of an Ant Design Linked/cascading Dropdown Select Using Next.js/React.js
I'm working on a React form using Ant Design's Form component. The form includes several dropdowns, including facility, specialization, and doctor. The doctor dropdown should be cleared whenever the facility or specialization dropdown values change, and the doctor dropdown should be repopulated based on the new facility and specialization values.
Here’s a summary of the setup:

I'm using Ant Design's Form component and useForm hook to manage the
form state.
The doctor dropdown is a custom component called SearchableDropDown
that fetches options based on the selected facility and
specialization.
I want the doctor dropdown to clear its value whenever the facility
or specialization changes.

Issue:
Despite calling form.setFieldsValue({ doctorId: undefined }); and setting setDoctor(null); in the useEffect hook, the doctorId dropdown does not clear its value as expected when facility or specialization changes.
Code Example:
you can find the code here on Stack Blitz
What I've Tried:

Setting the doctorId field value to undefined or null.
Adding a key prop to the SearchableDropDown to force
re-rendering.
Manually setting the doctor state to null.

Question:
How can I programmatically clear the doctorId dropdown value when either the facility or specialization dropdown changes in an Ant Design form? What is the correct approach to ensure that the doctor dropdown is cleared and reset based on the new facility and specialization selections?
Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!



In your app/page.tsx file, you forgot to add form={form} attribute in your antd Form Tag.

doctorId can be reset using form.resetFields(['doctorId']).


Modify your useEffect for Reset doctorId.
React.useEffect(() => {
    setDoctor(undefined);
    form.resetFields(['doctorId']);
}, [facility, specialization]);

Verify the following code:

NOTE: The code below is for guiding purposes, so it does not include lodash/debounce lib debounce function & Optional chaining (?.).


Please add it to your code as per requirement.



{ /* Start: Enum & JSON */}

let DDL_Type = {
  Facility: "ddl-facility",
  Doctor: "ddl-doctor",
  Specialization: "ddl-specialization",
};

let Specialization = [
  {
    label: "Addiction Psychiatry",
    value: "sp_1",
  },
  {
    label: "Aerospace Medicine",
    value: "sp_2",
  },
  {
    label: "Allergy and Immunology",
    value: "sp_3",
  },
  {
    label: "Anatomic Pathology",
    value: "sp_4",
  },
  {
    label: "Blood Banking/Transfusion Medicine",
    value: "sp_5",
  },
  {
    label: "Cardiology",
    value: "sp_6",
  },
  {
    label: "Microbiology",
    value: "sp_7",
  },
  {
    label: "Clinical Neurophysiology",
    value: "sp_8",
  },
  {
    label: "Clinical Pharmacology",
    value: "sp_9",
  },
  {
    label: "Colon and Rectal Surgery",
    value: "sp_10",
  },
];

let Facility = [
  {
    label: "Dar-ul-Sehat",
    value: "f_1",
  },
  {
    label: "Dow",
    value: "f_2",
  },
  {
    label: "Indus",
    value: "f_3",
  },
  {
    label: "MOH",
    value: "f_4",
  },
  {
    label: "My Facility",
    value: "f_5",
  },
];

let Doctor = [
  {
    _id: "d_1",
    facility: {
      _id: "f_2",
      name: "Dow",
    },
    firstName: "Azhar",
    lastName: "Sadiq",
    specialization: {
      _id: "sp_4",
      name: "Anatomic Pathology",
    },
  },
  {
    _id: "d_2",
    facility: {
      _id: "f_5",
      name: "My Facility",
    },
    firstName: "Haider",
    lastName: "Abbasi",
    specialization: {
      _id: "sp_7",
      name: "Microbiology",
    },
  },
  {
    _id: "d_3",
    facility: {
      _id: "f_5",
      name: "My Facility",
    },
    firstName: "Hammad",
    lastName: "Javeid",
    specialization: {
      _id: "sp_6",
      name: "Cardiology",
    },
  },
  {
    _id: "d_4",
    facility: {
      _id: "f_5",
      name: "My Facility",
    },
    firstName: "Zulqarnain",
    lastName: "jalil",
    specialization: {
      _id: "sp_6",
      name: "Cardiology",
    },
  },
];

{ /* End: Enum & JSON */}

{ /* Start: fetch_ddl Function */}

function fetch_ddl(search, ddl_type, otherQueryParams) {
  if (ddl_type === DDL_Type.Specialization)
    return Specialization.filter(
      (specialization) =>
        !search ||
        specialization.label.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
    );
    
  else if (ddl_type == DDL_Type.Facility)
    return Facility.filter(
      (facility) =>
        !search || facility.label.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
    );
    
  else if (ddl_type == DDL_Type.Doctor)
    return Doctor.filter((doctor) => {
      const matchesSearch =
        !search ||
        doctor.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) ||
        doctor.lastName.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase());

      const matchesFacility =
        !otherQueryParams.facilityId ||
        doctor.facility._id === otherQueryParams.facilityId;

      const matchesSpecialization =
        !specializationId ||
        doctor.specialization._id === otherQueryParams.specializationId;

      return matchesSearch && matchesFacility && matchesSpecialization;
    }).map((doctor) => ({
      label: `${doctor.firstName} ${doctor.lastName} (${doctor.specialization.name})`,
      value: doctor._id,
    }));
}

{ /* End: fetch_ddl Function */}

{ /* Start: SearchableDropDown Component */}

function SearchableDropDown({
  debounceTimeout = 800,
  onChange,
  ddl_type,
  queryParams,
  value,
  ...props
}) {

  const [fetching, setFetching] = React.useState(false);
  const [options, setOptions] = React.useState([]);
  const fetchRef = React.useRef(0);
  const [internalValue, setInternalValue] = React.useState(value);


  const debounceFetcher = React.useMemo(() => {
    const loadData = (value) => {
      fetchRef.current += 1;
      const fetchId = fetchRef.current;
      setOptions([]);
      setFetching(true);
      
      try {
        const newOptions = fetch_ddl(value, ddl_type, queryParams);
        if (fetchId === fetchRef.current) {
          setOptions(newOptions);
          setFetching(false);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
        setFetching(false);
      }
    };

    return setTimeout(loadData, debounceTimeout);
  }, [fetch_ddl, queryParams]);


  React.useEffect(() => {
    setOptions(fetch_ddl("", ddl_type, queryParams));
    setFetching(false);
  }, [queryParams, ddl_type, value]);


  React.useEffect(() => {
    setInternalValue(undefined);
  }, [queryParams]);


  const handleSelectChange = (value) => {
    if (onChange) onChange(value);
  };

  return (
    <antd.Select
      value={internalValue}
      labelInValue
      filterOption={false}
      onSearch={debounceFetcher}
      notFoundContent={fetching ? <antd.Spin size="small" /> : null}
      {...props}
      options={options}
      onChange={handleSelectChange}
    />
  );
}

{ /* End: SearchableDropDown Component */}

{ /* Start: App Component */}

function App() {
  const [form] = antd.Form.useForm(undefined);
  const [facility, setFacility] = React.useState("");
  const [specialization, setSpecialization] = React.useState("");
  const [doctor, setDoctor] = React.useState(undefined);

  const onFinish = (values) => {
    console.log("Received values of form: ", values);
  };

  const getParams = () => {
    var params = {};

    if (facility) params = { ...params, facilityId: facility };
    if (specialization)
      params = { ...params, specializationId: specialization };

    return params;
  };


  React.useEffect(() => {
    setDoctor(undefined);
    form.resetFields(["doctorId"]);
  }, [facility, specialization]);


  return (
    <div className="container mx-auto p-4">
      <antd.Form
        form={form}
        layout="vertical"
        onFinish={onFinish}
        className="bg-white p-6 rounded-lg shadow-md"
      >
        <h2 className="text-xl mb-4">Appointment Details</h2>
        
        <antd.Row gutter={16}>
          <antd.Col span={12}>
            <antd.Form.Item
              name="facilityId"
              label="Facility"
              getValueFromEvent={(option) => option.value}
              rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please select a facility" }]}
            >
              <SearchableDropDown
                allowClear={true}
                onChange={(val) => {
                  setFacility(val.value);
                }}
                showSearch
                style={{ width: "100%" }}
                placeholder="Search by facility"
                ddl_type={DDL_Type.Facility}
                className="flex-1"
              />
            </antd.Form.Item>
          </antd.Col>
          
          <antd.Col span={12}>
            <antd.Form.Item
              name="specializationId"
              label="Specialization"
              getValueFromEvent={(option) => option.value}
              rules={[
                { required: true, message: "Please select a specialization" },
              ]}
            >
              <SearchableDropDown
                onChange={(val) => {
                  setSpecialization(val.value);
                }}
                allowClear={true}
                showSearch
                style={{ width: "100%" }}
                placeholder="Search by specialization"
                ddl_type={DDL_Type.Specialization}
                className="flex-1"
              />
            </antd.Form.Item>
          </antd.Col>
        </antd.Row>
        
        <antd.Row gutter={16}>
          <antd.Col span={12}>
            <antd.Form.Item
              name="doctorId"
              label="Doctor"
              getValueFromEvent={(option) => option.value}
              rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please select a doctor" }]}
            >
              <SearchableDropDown
                value={doctor}
                allowClear={true}
                queryParams={getParams()}
                //onChange={(val) => setDoctor(val)}
                showSearch
                style={{ width: "100%" }}
                placeholder="Search by doctor"
                ddl_type={DDL_Type.Doctor}
                className="flex-1"
                key={"ddl-" + facility + "-" + specialization}
              />
            </antd.Form.Item>
          </antd.Col>
          
          <antd.Col span={12}>
            <antd.Form.Item
              name="dateTime"
              label="Appointment Date & Time"
              rules={[
                { required: true, message: "Please select a date and time" },
              ]}
            >
              <antd.DatePicker
                showTime
                minuteStep={15}
                needConfirm={false}
                use12Hours={true}
                format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"
                className="w-full"
                placeholder="Select Date & Time"
              />
            </antd.Form.Item>
          </antd.Col>
        </antd.Row>

        <antd.Form.Item>
          <antd.Button type="default" htmlType="submit" className="w-full">
            Book Appointment
          </antd.Button>
        </antd.Form.Item>
      </antd.Form>
    </div>
  );
}

{ /* End: App Component */}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.11.13/dayjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/antd/5.20.2/antd.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>




doctorId field is not reset is because you didn't connect form with Form component. Second there's no need to store facilityId, specializationId or any form field related field in state since you can get watch from form.getFieldValue or Form.useWatch('facilityId') if you watch the value of a field. You can use onChange on facilityId and specializationId to reset doctorId value form.resetFields(['doctorId])
Here's the complete code with some improvements
page.tsx
"use client";

import { Form, DatePicker, Button, Col, Row } from "antd";
import SearchableDropDown from "@/componets/SearchableDropDown";
import { DDL_Type } from "@/interfaces/common";
import { useCallback, useMemo } from "react";

type FormValuesType = {
    facilityId: string;
    specializationId: string;
    doctorId: string;
    dateTime: string;
};

export default function Home() {
    const [form] = Form.useForm<FormValuesType>();
    const onFinish = (values: FormValuesType) => {
        console.log("Received values of form: ", values);
    };

    const getDoctorFieldParams = useCallback(() => {
        const params = new URLSearchParams();
        const facility = form.getFieldValue("facilityId");
        const specialization = form.getFieldValue("specializationId");

        if (facility) params.append("facilityId", facility);
        if (specialization) params.append("specializationId", specialization);

        return params.toString();
    }, [form]);

    const resetDoctorIdDropdown = () => form.resetFields(["doctorId"]);

    return (
        <div className="container mx-auto p-4">
            <Form<FormValuesType>
                form={form}
                layout="vertical"
                onFinish={onFinish}
                className="bg-white p-6 rounded-lg shadow-md"
            >
                <h2 className="text-xl mb-4">Appointment Details</h2>
                <Row gutter={16}>
                    <Col span={12}>
                        <Form.Item<FormValuesType>
                            name="facilityId"
                            label="Facility"
                            rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please select a facility" }]}
                        >
                            <SearchableDropDown
                                allowClear={true}
                                onChange={resetDoctorIdDropdown}
                                showSearch
                                style={{ width: "100%" }}
                                placeholder="Search by facility"
                                ddl_type={DDL_Type.Facility}
                                className="flex-1"
                            />
                        </Form.Item>
                    </Col>
                    <Col span={12}>
                        <Form.Item<FormValuesType>
                            name="specializationId"
                            label="Specialization"
                            rules={[
                                { required: true, message: "Please select a specialization" },
                            ]}
                        >
                            <SearchableDropDown
                                onChange={resetDoctorIdDropdown}
                                allowClear={true}
                                showSearch
                                style={{ width: "100%" }}
                                placeholder="Search by doctor"
                                ddl_type={DDL_Type.Specialization}
                                className="flex-1"
                            />
                        </Form.Item>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row gutter={16}>
                    <Col span={12}>
                        <Form.Item<FormValuesType>
                            name="doctorId"
                            label="Doctor"
                            rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please select a doctor" }]}
                        >
                            <SearchableDropDown
                                allowClear={true}
                                getQueryParams={getDoctorFieldParams}
                                showSearch
                                style={{ width: "100%" }}
                                placeholder="Search by doctor"
                                ddl_type={DDL_Type.Doctor}
                                className="flex-1"
                            />
                        </Form.Item>
                    </Col>
                    <Col span={12}>
                        <Form.Item<FormValuesType>
                            name="dateTime"
                            label="Appointment Date & Time"
                            rules={[
                                { required: true, message: "Please select a date and time" },
                            ]}
                        >
                            <DatePicker
                                showTime
                                minuteStep={15}
                                needConfirm={false}
                                use12Hours={true}
                                format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"
                                className="w-full"
                                placeholder="Select Date & Time"
                            />
                        </Form.Item>
                    </Col>
                </Row>

                <Form.Item>
                    <Button type="default" htmlType="submit" className="w-full">
                        Book Appointment
                    </Button>
                </Form.Item>
            </Form>
        </div>
    );
}

SearchableDropDown.tsx
"use client";
import React, { useEffect, useMemo, useRef, useState } from "react";
import debounce from "lodash/debounce";
import { Form, Select, Spin } from "antd";
import type { SelectProps } from "antd/es/select";
import { DDL_Type, fetch_ddl } from "@/interfaces/common";

interface SearchableDropDownProps
    extends Omit<SelectProps<string>, "options" | "children"> {
    debounceTimeout?: number;
    getQueryParams?: () => string;
    onChange?: (value: string) => void;
    ddl_type: DDL_Type;
}

function SearchableDropDown(props: SearchableDropDownProps) {
    const { ddl_type, getQueryParams, debounceTimeout = 800, ...rest } = props;

    const fetchRef = useRef(0);
    const [fetching, setFetching] = useState(false);
    const [options, setOptions] = useState<{ label: string; value: string }[]>(
        [],
    );

    const debounceFetcher = useMemo(() => {
        const loadData = async (value: string) => {
            fetchRef.current += 1;
            const fetchId = fetchRef.current;
            setOptions([]);
            setFetching(true);
            try {
                const queryParams = getQueryParams ? getQueryParams() : "";
                const newOptions = await fetch_ddl(value, ddl_type, queryParams);
                if (fetchId === fetchRef.current) {
                    setOptions(newOptions);
                    setFetching(false);
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
                setFetching(false);
            }
        };

        return debounce(loadData, debounceTimeout);
    }, [ddl_type, getQueryParams, debounceTimeout]);

    useEffect(() => {
        debounceFetcher("");
    }, [debounceFetcher]);

    return (
        <Select
            filterOption={false}
            onSearch={debounceFetcher}
            loading={fetching}
            notFoundContent={fetching ? <Spin size="small" /> : null}
            {...rest}
            options={options}
        />
    );
}

export default SearchableDropDown;


Add an internal state internalValue inside your SearchableDropDown to track the passed value.
    const [internalValue, setInternalValue] = useState(value);

Pass it to the Select as value
    <Select
      value={internalValue}
      ...
    />

And the value can be set to undefined in case the change of the queryParams
  useEffect(() => {
    setInternalValue(undefined);
  }, [queryParams]);


I also have tried this but its not working. you can try my StackBlits, it has all in it

your code is making the doctor's dropdown empty, but i am still able to post the form and validation is not working  even if the dropdown is empty. you can see the console in the inspect. doctor dropdown still have value in it even we make it empty from internal state.
